# failed to start ceph-mon daemon

Tags: cloud, storage, ceph

I have built the ceph source code and make it installed with the following commands:

```
apt-get install a series of dependency packages
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

All these processes went well. When I type:

```
which ceph
```

Console shows:

```
/usr/local/bin/ceph
```

So I think I have install ceph successfully.
But when I try to start the ceph-mon daemon, console tells me:

```
start: unknown job: ceph-mon
```

And I have checked my service list by typing:

```
initctl list | grep ceph
```

And the output is blank.

Somebody could tell me why?

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions here http://ceph.com/docs/master/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to touch the file `sysvinit`. For example, assume the host name of monitor node is `node1` and the cluster name is by default, use this command `touch /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-node1/sysvinit` before starting the monitor process. This solve my problem when getting the unknown error.

Answer (score 0):

The **make install** target of Ceph does not install the [upstart script](https://github.com/ceph/ceph/blob/giant/src/upstart/ceph-mon.conf). The best option is to install packages with **apt-get install ceph**. If you need to run from modified sources, you can with **ceph-mon -i a**, assuming the monitor data already exists.

Answer (score 0):

can you run `cepn-mon -i <your-mon-id>`, I solve this by :

(I am at the same situation as yours, I am based on firefly & I compile & make install from the cource code.)

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
fsid=`uuidgen`                                                                  
host="your-mon-host"                                                                  
ipaddr="your-mon-ip-addr"                                                              

echo "[global]" > ./ceph.sample.conf                                            
echo "fsid = ${fsid}" >> ./ceph.sample.conf                                     
echo "mon initial members=${host}" >> ./ceph.sample.conf                        
echo "mon host = ${ipaddr}" >> ./ceph.sample.conf                               
cat ./popular_settings.txt >> ./ceph.sample.conf                                
cp ./ceph.sample.conf /etc/ceph/ceph.conf                                       

rm -rf /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-${host}/done                                      

sudo ceph-authtool --create-keyring /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-${host}.mon.keyring --gen-key -n mon. --cap mon 'allow *'
sudo ceph-authtool --create-keyring /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring --gen-key -n client.admin --set-uid=0 --cap mon 'allow *' --cap osd 'a    llow *' --cap mds 'allow'

sudo chmod +r /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-${host}.mon.keyring                        
sudo chmod +r /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring                               

sudo ceph-authtool /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-${host}.mon.keyring --import-keyring /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring


monmaptool --create --add ${host} ${ipaddr} --fsid ${fsid} /tmp/monmap --clobber


#rm -rf /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-${host}                                          
sudo ceph-mon --mkfs -i ${host} --monmap /tmp/monmap --keyring /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-${host}.mon.keyring 

touch /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-${host}/done                                       
touch /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-${host}/upstart  
ps aux | grep "ceph-mon"    #there should be no ceph-mon                                  
ceph-mon -i ${host} 
ps aux | grep "ceph-mon"    #there we've got a ceph-mon running                           

ceph osd tree
```

Comment: In my case, manual deployment with the make, it creates and runs the mon but still the "ceph osd tree" doesn't return any output! At the end of this step, I expect to have ceph id on hard disks (the output of "lsblk" would disply that) but I don't! Any ideas?